# SQL Server select all rows into single column with repeating column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code and its temporary tables so you can run it.

```
    create table #hourly_sales(
    id int identity(1,1),
    tenant_code varchar(13),
    hour_code int,
    net_sale_per_hour decimal(18,2)
    )


    insert into #hourly_sales(tenant_code,hour_code,net_sale_per_hour)
    values('1234567890000',1,200),('1234567890000',2,500),('1234567890000',3,400)


    select * from #hourly_sales

    drop table #hourly_sales
```

This will give you this output

```
  id          tenant_code   hour_code   net_sale_per_hour
  ----------- ------------- ----------- -------------------
  1           1234567890000 1           200.00
  2           1234567890000 2           500.00
  3           1234567890000 3           400.00
```

I wanted them all to select in a single column with the tenant code grouped and net sale is summed up

My goal:

```
  id          tenant_code   hour_code   net_sale_per_hour hour_code net_sale_per_hour
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  1           1234567890000 1           200.00            2         500     

  hour_code net_sale_per_hour   total_net_sale
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  3         400
```

and so on

My attempt:

```
    declare @sum decimal(18,2);
    set @sum = (select sum(net_sale_per_hour) from #hourly_sales);

    select TOP 1
        id,
        tenant_code,
        hour_code,
        net_sale_per_hour,
        @sum
    from #hourly_sales
```

This is all I got for you I need your help.

Comment: Try searching Google/Stack Overflow for "SQL pivot query" and you will find a good suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for giving us a temp table so we can play with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes if you have limited columns, only 24, it is easier just to spell it out.

```
select tenant_code, 
    sum(case when hour_code = 1 then net_sale_per_hour else null end) as '01',
    sum(case when hour_code = 2 then net_sale_per_hour else null end) as '02',
    sum(case when hour_code = 3 then net_sale_per_hour else null end) as '03'
    from #hourly_sales
    group by tenant_code
```

[image]

Comment: this is awesome but what if i have more datas to come?

Comment: More datas to come?  Update your question with an example.